# Pause SQL server replication temporarily

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

We have a transactional replication setup using 3 SQL Servers, 1st as publisher, 2nd as distributor, and 3rd as subscriber.

We have an activity to change the location of the replicated DB (subscriber) using de-attach  and attach method. During this activity, I will need to stop the SQL server and hence all replicated transactions will fail.

What's the proper way to pause the replication during this activity, so when I attach the DB again and start the SQL service, replication will resume normally.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please see the following link for details of how to accomplish this:

[Start and Stop a Replication Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

The above article doesn't appear to give information on stopping the distribution agent, this can be achieved by using the stored procs detailed in the link below:

[Start/Stop SQL Server Replication Agent using TSQL](http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/startstop-sql-server-replication-agent/)

Comment: It does not include how to start/stop The Distribution Agent